# proguard doesnt preserve string values

Tags: android, annotations, proguard, obfuscation, wizard

I would like to use proguard for obfuscation and I have the following issue:
I use wizardroid package which has the option to preserve the user input among steps, that's being done using @ContextVariable annotation.

eventually all values are collected and inserted to the sql db, however i am getting an exception since some of the values are null.

When I am using -dontobfuscate everything works properly

Someone has an idea how can overcome this issue? I searched and implemented several solutions but none was helpful

Thank you for your assistance in advanced

Comment: So I figured out that the mappings that proguard does to the class members causing wrong assignments in the String variable. can someone suggest a way to keep proguard from obfuscating the String variables below?

public class cAd_De_Wi extends WizardFragment implements View.OnClickListener {

   Button nextButton,previousButton;
   long rtrn_value;
    @ContextVariable
    protected static String mMG_I,mSN_RC,mS_WCO,
            usm,au,au_pa,priv,priv_pa,
            mDEV_NA,mH_PLAT,mSN_V;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue resolved, I added the following to the proguard-rules file

```
-keepclassmembers class * {
    static java.lang.String *;
}
```

That did the trick :-)